# Bracket Notation is Accessing Object With Quotation Marks

Tags: javascript, object, redux

I'm accessing an object using `bracket notation` in javascript. For some reason it's placing the value with quotation marks... NOT what I want.

```
console.log(positions)
{
    element: null,
    elementTwo: null,
    elementThree: null,
    "elementThree": 1
}
```

**Some More Info**

I have the following state in my `reducer` in redux...

```
const initialState = {
  positions: {
    element: null,
    elementTwo: null,
    elementThree: null
  }
};
```

I should be able to manipulate it easy enough

```
case SET_POSITION:
  console.log(action.payload.element) //elementTwo
  return {
    ...state,
    positions: {
      ...state.positions,
      [action.payload.element]: action.payload.position
    }
  };
```

If I `console.log(action.paylod.element)` and `console.log('elementThree')` they are identical.

And, if I access using the following, it works:

```
case SET_POSITION:
  console.log(action.payload.element) //elementTwo
  return {
    ...state,
    positions: {
      ...state.positions,
      ['elementThree']: action.payload.position 
    }
  };
```

What's going on here?

Comment: What props do you have in your state after doing [action.payload.element]: action.payload.position?

Comment: @Valerii Thanks for the response. Ended up figuring it out :) Will be posting an answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

I'm receiving the `action.payload.position` from a serial port connection.

There's a `\r` which doesn't show at the end of the string... Use `.trim()` to remove this!

More info see:

[Why are these two identical strings not equal in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507868/why-are-these-two-identical-strings-not-equal-in-javascript)